# DIsplay SELECT list values as SELECTED from DB - Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a `Multi SELECT List` where admin can select more thatn one positions for the player where a player can play

*/com/models/forms/player.xml*

```
 <field name="sec_position_name" type="checkboxes" label="Secondary Pos." >
        <option value="Left">Left</option>
        <option value="Middle">Middle</option>
        <option value="Right">Right</option>
 </field>
```

And these are the functions in

*com/models/player.php* that loads the Form data

```
protected function loadFormData() {
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->
            getUserState('com_football.edit.player.data', array());

    if (empty($data)) {
        $data = $this->getItem();
    }

    return $data;
}

public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) {
    $form = $this->loadForm('com_football.player', 
                            'player', array('control' => 'jform',
                            'load_data' => $loadData));        

    return $form;
}
```

And here is how form is displayed in the Layout.

*com/views/player/tmpl/edit.php*

```
<ul class="adminformlist">
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('optional') as $field): ?>
   <li><?php echo $field->label; ?>
   <?php echo $field->input; ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

**How can I display already existing values from DB as SELECTED...???**

Note: I have asked [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649606/display-matched-checkboxes-as-checked-from-db-joomla-2-5)(maybe this clears more)

Answer (score 0):

Write method which get already existing values from database. Let's say it returns an array with values. Next step is to create field by custom type and there get existing values and compare with new values in a loop

Comment: sorry but this is just verbel solution|logic which I know too ... I want some hints about code .. at least hint about where Foo code should be written......

Comment: I have acheived my task by using MULTISELECT joomla field ...

Thanks a lot for your effort